# How to calculate distance between some randomly generated matrix and a given array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, distance

Here in this code, 50 random coordinates are generated(population size 50). 
I have an array,

```
B = [150 90; -100 -120; -80 130; 140 -70; 60 120; -90 -130].
```

I want to calculate the distance of each 50 coordinates from each of the coordinates of B array. After calculating the distance, I have to preserve all of the distance values separately in an array(or matrix) to retrieve them afterwards.
Please help me to calculate the distance.

```
clear all
clc

%Common Parameter Setting
N=2;        % Number of variables
M=50;       % Populations size 50
F=0.5;      % Mutation factor
C=0.9;      % Crossover rate
I_max=20;   % Max iteration time
Run=1;      % The number of test time
X_max=[100,100];
X_min=[-100,-100];

%Func=@Rastrigin;

% 2.The whole test loop
for r=1:Run
    iter=0;
    % 1.Generate MxN matrix
    for m=1:M
        for n=1:N
            X(m,n)=X_min(n)+rand()*(X_max(n)-X_min(n));
        end
        fprintf('value of X:');
        disp(X);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not completely understand the last part. But if you have 2 lists of coordinates, say

```
x = randn(10,2); %10 points in 2D
y = randn(3,2); % 3 others points in 2D
```

and you want the pairwise distance between all points in `x` and all points in `y`, you can use `pdist2`

```
D = pdist2(x,y);
```

Now `D(1,2)` will be the Euclidean distance from `x(1)` to `y(2)` and so on.

Comment: So, for my above mentioned code, where X has the random 50 co-ordinates and B has the 6 specific co-ordinates, should I write--> D = pdist2(X, B) ?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.